# Incomplete \ifx using \ifnum in beamer frame inside tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I want to use the following `tikzpicture` in an animation, and if the macro `\iFrame` is unequal to zero, part of it should not be drawn. If I use the following code in the `standalone` class without the `frame` environment it works as expected, and if I use `\ifnum` *outside* the `tikzpicture` it also works as expected. However if I use `\ifnum` inside a `tikzpicture` inside a `frame`, compilation stops with a `Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 40.` error. I would like to know why.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    axis/.style={-stealth,line width=1.5pt},
    xaxis/.style={axis,red},
    yaxis/.style={axis,green},
    zaxis/.style={axis,blue}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[line width = 1pt]
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\iFrame{15}
            \begin{scope}[shift={(0,0)},rotate=30]
                \filldraw[fill=violet,fill opacity=.5] (0,0) circle (2.2 and 0.6);
                \draw[xaxis] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0);
                \draw[yaxis] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0);
                \draw[zaxis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1);
                \node[left] {\( \Psi_a \)};
                \coordinate (pa1) at (2,0);
                \fill (pa1) circle (1mm);
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[shift={({\iFrame/10+4*cos(30)},0)},rotate=330]
                \filldraw[fill=orange,fill opacity=.5] (0,0) circle (2.2 and 0.6);
                \draw[xaxis] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0);
                \draw[yaxis] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0);
                \draw[zaxis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1);
                \node[above left] {\( \Psi_b \)};
                \coordinate (pb1) at (-2,0);
                \fill (pb1) circle (1mm);
            \end{scope}
            \ifnum\iFrame=0\relax
                \begin{scope}[shift={({2*cos(30)},{2*sin(30)})}]
                    \draw[xaxis] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0);
                    \draw[yaxis] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0);
                    \draw[zaxis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1);
                    \node[above right] {\( \Psi_j \)};
                \end{scope}
            \fi
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{frame}[fragile]`

Comment: In addition to what @egreg is saying, you may load `\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}` and then selectively set the scope invisible,

Comment: @egreg Thanks! Why is that needed and why is it not default behavior? @marmot Thanks for the suggestion, but I plan to use the `animate` package.

Comment: @MaxSnippe `fragile` requires the content of the frame be written out to another file and then read back, so (1) you don't usually want all those extra files around and (2) you don't typically want the increase in compilation time from doing it that way. Hence, use it when you need it.

Comment: @egreg Do you want to write an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution is to use the `fragile` option to the `frame` environment, so the contents is written verbatim to an auxiliary file and `beamer` doesn't get confused while reading the material. I'm not really sure where the problem is, but it surely resides with the “raw” conditional.

Indeed, a different solution to do the conditional like

```
        \ifnumequal{\iFrame}{0}
          {
            \begin{scope}[shift={({2*cos(30)},{2*sin(30)})}]
                \draw[xaxis] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0);
                \draw[yaxis] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0);
                \draw[zaxis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1);
                \node[above right] {\( \Psi_j \)};
            \end{scope}
          }{}
```

Don't forget the empty braces for the “false” branch. No “raw” conditional is scanned and all goes well. The construction `\ifnumequal` is defined by `etoolbox`, which is automatically loaded by `beamer`.